# I want to delete redundant lines in my table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a huge table where there is information of 2 professionals in each line that goes like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame("Date" = c(1,2,3,4), "prof1" = c(25,59,10,5), "prof2" = c(5,7,8,25))

#  Date  prof1  prf2
#1 1      25     5
#2 2      59     7
#3 3      10     8
#4 4      5      25
...      ...    ...
```

I want to delete the line 4 because its the same with line 1, just with alternate values.

So I created a copy os that table with the values of the columns B and C switched like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame("Date" = c(1,2,3,4), "prof2" = c(5,7,8,25), "prof1" = c(25,59,10,5))

#  Date  prof2  prof1
#1 1      5     25
#2 2      7     59
#3 3      8     10
#4 4      25    5
...      ...    ...
```

And executed the code:

`df1<- df1[!do.call(paste, df1[2:3]) %in% do.call(paste, df2[2:3]), ]`

But it end up deleting the line 1 as well. Giving me this table:

```
#  Date  prof2  prof1
#2 2      7     59
#3 3      8     10
...      ...    ...
```

when what I wanted was this:

```
#  Date  prof2  prof1
#1 1      5     25
#2 2      7     59
#3 3      8     10
...      ...    ...
```

How can I delete only one of the lines that are similar to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about which one of the duplicates you keep,  you can just make sure that
prof2 > prof1 and then remove duplicates.

```
SWAP = which(df2$prof2 < df2$prof1)
temp = df2$prof2
df2$prof2[SWAP] = df2$prof1[SWAP]
df2$prof1[SWAP] = temp[SWAP]

df2 = df2[!duplicated(df2[,2:3]), ]
df2
  Date prof2 prof1
1    1    25     5
2    2    59     7
3    3    10     8
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `apply` to loop over the rows of the dataset, `sort`, them, get the transpose, apply `duplicated` on it to get a logical vector and subset

```
df1[!duplicated(t(apply(df1[-1], 1, sort))),]
#    Date prof1 prof2
#1    1    25     5
#2    2    59     7
#3    3    10     8
```

---

Or another option is `pmin/pmax`

```
subset(df1, !duplicated(cbind(pmin(prof1, prof2), pmax(prof1, prof2))))
#  Date prof1 prof2
#1    1    25     5
#2    2    59     7
#3    3    10     8
```

---

Or using `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter( !duplicated(cbind(pmin(prof1, prof2), pmax(prof1, prof2))))
```